# remove parts from a pdb file using python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a pdb file (input.pdb) and I want to remove some specific parts from the file and write it back without this part (out.pdb), 
for example, read (input.pdb) remove from chain H residue 92 till chain H residue 105 then write the rest of the file (input.pdb without the removed section) into a new file (out.pdb)

Comment: See the biopython [Bio.PDB](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB-module.html) module [tutorial](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/cookbook/biopdb_faq.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it using biopython's `Bio.PDB` package. We're using the structure `1y26.pdb` as an example, so we have to load it first:

```
import Bio.PDB as bpdb

s = bpdb.PDBParser().get_structure('temp', '1y26.pdb')

start_res=20
end_res=30
chain_id = 'X'
```

This is the interesting part here. You create a subclass of `Bio.PDB.Select` which tells the pdb output class which residues to save. For each residue in the structure, it will call the `accept_residue` method of the following class and save the residue if it returns true and skip it if it returns false. The same goes for the chain id.

```
class ResSelect(bpdb.Select):
    def accept_residue(self, res):
        if res.id[1] >= start_res and res.id[1] <= end_res and res.parent.id == chain_id:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Finally we create the class that does the actual saving and pass it the selection class defined above.

```
io = bpdb.PDBIO()
io.set_structure(s)
io.save('1y26_cropped.pdb', ResSelect())
```

That's it, that's all. Hopefully.

Comment: thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/899470/juniper this is really helpful, the only problem is that the residue number isn't the only identifier I need to specify the residue number and chain together, so is it possible to modify your script to do so? thanks

Comment: Sure. Just add the `accept_chain` method which works just like the `accept_residue` method. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/899470/juniper pay attention your script will remove all the residues between 20-30 and also all the chain "X" (offcourse after reversing the order of the return case in the second function "accept_chain"). simply all what I want is to have something like: if (res.id[1] >= start and res.id[1] <= end and chain.id == mychain), then return false or else return true, so is that possible?

Comment: Right you are. Just check the id of the parent of the residue then.